# Error in previewing Reporting Service limiting no of rows per page

Tags: reporting-services

I use SSRS and I added a group with fx

```
=Ceiling(Rownumber(nothing)/10)
```

but this error is displayed when I press preview report

> "A sort expression for tablix 'Table1' uses the Row Number function 
>   row number cannot be used in sort expression"

I made sure there are no any sort expressions

What should I do ?
thanks in advance ...

Comment: what's your requirement.

Comment: I have for example 20 ID = 1,2,3,...,20 records and I wrote this line
=Ceiling(Rownumber(nothing)/10) in the group expression but now it displays 2 pages only first page with one record  ID=10and  ID = 20 in the second page , but I need 10 records per every page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use the following expression,

```
=Floor((RowNumber(Nothing) - 1) / 10)
```

Also set the **Page break at and** property for the group.